# Feeds - Background process vs Batch API

Tags: 7, feeds, cron

I've being using Feeds to import a medium sized amount of nodes in a daily basis.
I'm using Elysia cron in order to get fine tuning cron settings.

Here's my flow :

1. Every day at 02 am a cron task is triggered
2. This task loads a list of files from its settings, and for each of these files, it triggers a feeds import by calling :

```
$myFeed->startImport()
```

If you take a look at this startImport method, you will see something like this :

```
public function startImport() {
    module_invoke_all('feeds_before_import', $this);
    $config = $this->importer->getConfig();
    if ($config['process_in_background']) {
      $this->startBackgroundJob('import');
    }
    else {
      $this->startBatchAPIJob(t('Importing'), 'import');
    }
}
```

So, we have two ways of calling the Feeds importer, either using the Background JOB api (which I suppose to be this : https://drupal.org/project/background_process) or the Batch API (https://drupal.org/node/180528).

**Since I'm starting the feeds importer from a cron task, which one is more appropriate for this scenario ?**

*Can we see the Background process as an enhancement of the Batch API ?*

Comment: I actually call the drush command. There is a very long thread and numerous patches to implement this. https://drupal.org/node/608408

Comment: Thanks for the link @Queenvictoria. Can you maybe elaborate the Drush usage in an answer? For a periodic import, should we add "drush feeds-import xxx --options" in the crontab?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've been digging through this code, and Feeds does not use [Background Process](https://www.drupal.org/project/background_process).

It uses [Job Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/job_scheduler)

From **FeedsSource.inc**:

```
  /**
   * Background job helper. Starts a background job using Job Scheduler.
   *
   * Execute the first batch chunk of a background job on the current page load,
   * moves the rest of the job processing to a cron powered background job.
   *
   * Executing the first batch chunk is important, otherwise, when a user
   * submits a source for import or clearing, we will leave her without any
   * visual indicators of an ongoing job.
   *
   * @see FeedsSource::startImport().
   * @see FeedsSource::startClear().
   *
   * @param $method
   *   Method to execute on importer; one of 'import' or 'clear'.
   *
   * @throws Exception $e
   */
  protected function startBackgroundJob($method) {
    if (FEEDS_BATCH_COMPLETE != $this->$method()) {
      $job = array(
        'type' => $this->id,
        'id' => $this->feed_nid,
        'period' => 0,
        'periodic' => FALSE,
      );
      JobScheduler::get("feeds_source_{$method}")->set($job);
    }
  }
```

Job Scheduler in turn uses cron to complete jobs, so you're not really saving yourself anything if you are already calling this from cron.

The core Drupal [Batch API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21batch.inc/7) uses AJAX to break up jobs into batches. You can't start a Batch API batch from cron. If you don't have JS and try to start a Batch with the core API, you'll still need to watch the progress bar move across the screen. If you abandon your browser during a batch, it will stop working.

Contrary to what the *previously* accepted answer above states, *the core Batch API **does not** use cron*

[Background process](https://www.drupal.org/project/background_process) is now a suite of modules, and it does now include a Batch API module. These are 2 separate modules, which are not related to the Job Schedule module. We can't refer to Background Job/Process as 1 thing. These are 2 unrelated modules.

The key differences are as follows:

**Drupal Batch API** uses your browser to make new requests to the server at regular intervals. This does not work from a cron job

**Job Scheduler** uses cron to call on a set of scheduled jobs during cron execution. There is a limit on how long the process can run during cron, so this is not ideal for long-running processes. It also is not good if you need your import to occur in a timely manner, when you have your cron job only running at night. Scheduling a new Job during cron is a bit backwards, since it might not be until the next cron run that the job is actually dispatched (depending on if your `hook_cron()` is called before or after `job_scheduler_cron()`)

**Background process / Background Batch** uses server-side http requests to chain steps of a process together. This is ideal for long-running processes that need to be started immediately. You can also start a long-running process from `hook_cron()` with this module, and it will run until finished.

I know you probably don't need this information now, but I did when I found this page from Google.

The information provided in the *previously* accepted answer is incorrect, and led me down the wrong path.

Comment: In my case, I decided to use drush + cron.

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant information tmsimont, I have updated my answer below to point to your accepted response.

Answer (score 1):

**My below response is incorrect, please refer to the accepted answer for an accurate outline.** I have left it there to show my thought process, where I got my information from and hopefully to stop others going wrong in the future.

**Kyle**

---

*My [understanding](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70437/background-process-module-limitations-and-efficiency) is that the Background Job/Process is lightweight and can be easily run at peak times, as it will timeout if it runs for too long (predetermined), and interestingly is not actually a true background process module. However, the Batch API simply runs the jobs from the Cron as quickly as possible. I think it may be a case of semantics here, and that they both the the same job, however Background Job may be a little more convoluted in how it operates. Personally, at 0200 there is next to no activity on my site, so I would run my imports through Batch. If, however, you find you are under high stress (or have a low capacity server) at this time, then I would suggest Background Process/Jobs.*

*Hopefully this helps!*

Comment: this is not correct, please see my post below