# Can a batch process be stopped

Tags: 7, batch-operations

Is there a way to force a batch process to stop if some kind of error occurs?  In particular, I have a batch that starts with saving a record to a database. Each subsequent batch operation depends on the database insert working correctly.  I'd like to force the batch to stop if the first batch fails.

The batch is called like this

```
$batch = array(
    'operations' => $operations,
    'finished' => 'mymodule_batch_finished',
    'title' => t('Merging records'),
    'init_message' => t('Starting processing'),
    'progress_message' => t('Processed @current out of @total.'),
    'error_message' => t('Processing has encountered an error'),
    'file' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/forms/mymodule.inc'
);
```

where `$operations` is the array of functions to call.

Each function uses PDO to update the database.  I'm trying to figure out how to stop the subsequent `$operations` from being called if the query in the current operation fails.

```
try {
  $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $sth->bindParam(':newid',$new_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $sth->bindParam(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
  if($sth->execute()) {
    $context['results']['[] = $sth->rowCount();
  }
  else {
    // TODO: stop processing due to an error
  }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  // TODO: stop processing due to an error
}
```

If an error occurs, I want to bypass the remaining operations and go straight to `mymodule_batch_finished`

Comment: How do you currently perform the saving into the database? What triggers the batch process?

Comment: added details to answer your questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Inside your batch callback, where you do the batch work, you should be able to set `$context['finished']` to `1`, and that will signal to Drupal that the batch is complete.

So, in your case:

```
$error = FALSE;
try {
  $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $sth->bindParam(':newid',$new_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $sth->bindParam(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
  if($sth->execute()) {
    $context['results'][] = $sth->rowCount();
  }
  else {
    $error = TRUE;
  }
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  $error = TRUE;
}
// If there was an error, immediately complete the batch process.
if ($error) {
  $context['finished'] = 1;
}
```

And, even better, you can pass in an error message in the `$context` as well, which you can check for in your finished callback, then display to the end user in case of failure.

If you want to *immediately* stop processing anything in other callbacks in the `$operations` list, you might also need to check for a static variable at the beginning of each callback, and skip the callback if it's in an error condition. You could try using `variable_get`/`variable_set`, or some other mechanism that persists between page requests. This would definitely be a hackish/last-resort solution, though!

See also:

- [How does the batch API work internally?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/51007/26)
- [Batch operations API documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/batch/7)

Answer (score -1):

Can you try below code ?

```
$result = array('status' => FALSE, 'data' => $message);
die(json_encode($result));
```

Comment: That'll just show me an error page.  I want to bypass the remaining operations and go straight to `mymodule_batch_finished`