# Show progress of code executed on form submit

Tags: forms

I have a form in my site (custom module) where the user chooses some options and depending on those options, some code is executed.

The code basically executes shell commands on a remote server and at the moment, all the **drupal_set_message** commands are only shown after all commands are executed.

Is there any way that I can show those messages as soon as each part of the code is executed?

```
function mymodule_connect() {
    $host = '<my ip address>';
    $username = '<my username>';
    $password = '<my password>';

    $connection = ssh2_connect($host, 22);
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password);

    return $connection;
}

function mymodule_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {

    $delete_load = $form_state['values']['delete_load'];
    $change_load = $form_state['values']['change_load'];
    $load_number = $form_state['values']['check_load'];


    if($change_load == 1) {
        # DELETE
        # perform some command

        # LOAD
        # perform other command

        drupal_set_message('Deleting. Please wait...', 'error');
        drupal_set_message('Changing load. Please wait...', 'warning');
    } elseif ($delete_load == 1 && $change_load == 0) {
        # DELETE    
        drupal_set_message('Deleting. Please wait...', 'error');

        $command = "<some shell script command to send>";

        $connection = mymodule_connect();

        $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
        stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
        $output = stream_get_contents($stream);
        dpm($output);

        ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit');
        unset($connection);

    } else {
        # do nothing
    }

    # OTHER DIFFERENT SET OF COMMANDS TO SEND
    drupal_set_message('Configuring. Please wait...', 'status');

    $commands = array(
        "<some shell script command to send>",
        "<some shell script command to send>",
        "<some shell script command to send>",
    );

    $connection = mymodule_connect();

    foreach ($commands as $command) {
        $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
        stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
        $output = stream_get_contents($stream);
        dpm($output);
    };

    ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit');
    unset($connection);

    return t('Success');
}
```

Comment: Drupal 7 I assume?

Comment: Javascript & ajax is the answer, but I'm sure someone can get more specific than that.

Comment: Sure. Is Drupal 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mohammed Gomma mentioned you need to use Batch API to achieve the same. The implementation of batch api may look something like code given below:

1. Create Batch array
2. Create function to execute commands and call them using batch operation
3. set context message in the function created
4. create finish callback

   function mymodule_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {

   ```
         $delete_load = $form_state['values']['delete_load'];
         $change_load = $form_state['values']['change_load'];
         $load_number = $form_state['values']['check_load'];


         if ($change_load == 1) {
           # DELETE
           # perform some command
           # LOAD
           # perform other command

           drupal_set_message('Deleting. Please wait...', 'error');
           drupal_set_message('Changing load. Please wait...', 'warning');
         }
         elseif ($delete_load == 1 && $change_load == 0) {
           # DELETE    
           drupal_set_message('Deleting. Please wait...', 'error');

           $command = "<some shell script command to send>";



           $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
           stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
           $output = stream_get_contents($stream);
           dpm($output);

           ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit');
           unset($connection);
         }
         else {
           # do nothing
         }

         # OTHER DIFFERENT SET OF COMMANDS TO SEND
         drupal_set_message('Configuring. Please wait...', 'status');

         $commands = array(
           "<some shell script command to send>",
           "<some shell script command to send>",
           "<some shell script command to send>",
         );

         $batch = array(
           'finished' => 'batch_example_finished',
           'title' => t('Processing Example Batch'),
           'init_message' => t('Example Batch is starting.'),
           'progress_message' => t('Processed @current out of @total.'),
           'error_message' => t('Example Batch has encountered an error.'),
         );
         foreach ($commands as $command) {
           $batch['operations'][] = array('_batch_execute_command', array($command));
         };

         batch_set($batch);



         return t('Success');
       }

       function _batch_execute_command($command, &$context) {
         $connection = mymodule_connect();
         $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
         stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
         $output = stream_get_contents($stream);
         dpm($output);
         ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit');              
         unset($connection);
         $context['message'] = t('Now processing %command', array('%command' => $command));
         if ($context['sandbox']['progress'] != $context['sandbox']['max']) {
           $context['finished'] = $context['sandbox']['progress'] / $context['sandbox']['max'];
         }
       }

       /**
        * Batch 'finished' callback
        */
       function batch_example_finished($success, $results, $operations) {
         if ($success) {
           // Here we do something meaningful with the results.
           $message = t('@count items successfully processed:', array('@count' => count($results)));
           // $message .= theme('item_list', $results);  // D6 syntax
           $message .= theme('item_list', array('items' => $results));
           drupal_set_message($message);
         }
         else {
           // An error occurred.
           // $operations contains the operations that remained unprocessed.
           $error_operation = reset($operations);
           $message = t('An error occurred while processing %error_operation with arguments: @arguments', array('%error_operation' => $error_operation[0], '@arguments' => print_r($error_operation[1], TRUE)));
           drupal_set_message($message, 'error');
         }
       }
   ```

**Nested batch example:**

```
function gamify_batch_form($form, $form_state) {
  return array(
    'submit' => array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#title' => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'submit',
    ),
  );
}

function gamify_batch_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $batch = array(
    'finished' => 'batch_example_finished',
    'title' => t('Processing Example Batch'),
    'init_message' => t('Example Batch is starting.'),
    'progress_message' => t('Processed @current out of @total.'),
    'error_message' => t('Example Batch has encountered an error.'),
  );
  $commands = array(
    'hi',
    'hello',
    'world',
    'dear',
    'world',
  );
  foreach ($commands as $command) {
    $batch['operations'][] = array('_batch_execute_command', array($command));
  };

  batch_set($batch);
}

function _batch_execute_command($command, &$context) {
  file_get_contents("https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246767/show-progress-of-code-executed-on-form-submit/247718?noredirect=1#comment303466_247718");
  if($command == 'world'){
    $batch = array(
      'finished' => 'batch_example_finished',
      'title' => t('Processing Example Batch'),
      'init_message' => t('Example Batch is starting.'),
      'progress_message' => t('Processed @current out of @total.'),
      'error_message' => t('Example Batch has encountered an error.'),
    );
    $commands = array(
      'hi 1',
      'hello 2',
      'dear 3',
    );
    foreach ($commands as $innercommand) {
      $batch['operations'][] = array('_batch_execute_command', array($innercommand));
    };

    batch_set($batch);
  }
  $context['message'] = t('Now processing %command', array('%command' => $command));
  if ($context['sandbox']['progress'] != $context['sandbox']['max']) {
    $context['finished'] = $context['sandbox']['progress'] / $context['sandbox']['max'];
  }
}

/**
 * Batch 'finished' callback
 */
function batch_example_finished($success, $results, $operations) {
  if ($success) {
    // Here we do something meaningful with the results.
    $message = t('@count items successfully processed:', array('@count' => count($results)));
    // $message .= theme('item_list', $results);  // D6 syntax
    $message .= theme('item_list', array('items' => $results));
    drupal_set_message($message);
  }
  else {
    // An error occurred.
    // $operations contains the operations that remained unprocessed.
    $error_operation = reset($operations);
    $message = t('An error occurred while processing %error_operation with arguments: @arguments', array('%error_operation' => $error_operation[0], '@arguments' => print_r($error_operation[1], TRUE)));
    drupal_set_message($message, 'error');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. @Vishal Patil: When you call _batch_execute_command, I think you don't need the $stream. I removed it but I still have an issue. The variable $connection is not passed to the function.

Comment: You can create connection inside _batch_execute_command() instead of passing the argument. Please check updated sample code.

Comment: Thanks Vishal Patil. Now is working. I am missing just one thing. If I add a call to a new function inside "foreach ($commands as $command) {", can I add it to the batch? The thing is: for each command, if some variable is equal to something, I will have another set of commands that I need to run in a batch.

Comment: EDIT: noticed now that for that new batch, I need a value that is generated inside the first batch. So this seems a case that I need batches inside batches. Don't know if this is the best way to do it

Comment: You can try creating nested batch inside _batch_execute_command() function if the condition is matched. Check answers for nested batch example.

Comment: Progress percent may look confusing because of nested batch.

Comment: All working well now. Many many thanks Vishal. I'm just missing something that I can't find information. If I close the page or reload after I submit the form, the processes run well but I can't see the information. Is there a way to check if some process is running and view that information?

Answer (score 4):

Surely you need to implement [Batch API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/batch-api/overview) to achieve what you need, and keep the user notified for what's happening in the background.

[Very similar question that will help you more.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50996/how-does-the-batch-api-work-internally) Read it carefully.

These modules will help you:

1. [Progerss](https://www.drupal.org/project/progress) This is an attempt to implement a generic framework for keeping track of any progress
2. [Background progress](https://www.drupal.org/project/background_process) takes over the existing Batch API and runs batch jobs in a background process